# In SQL, can you add a foreign key constraint on a set of attributes, so that all of them must be on the same row of the referenced table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-database

I have the following scenario: there are developers *studios*, each of which made *games* and every game has a set of *maps*. The maps are not unique to a game as there are maps that were remade in different games by different developers studios. Though, a game is unique to a studio as in my scenario no studio ever remade an already existing game from another studio.

Every map then has a set of *solvers*. Two different maps of the same game can have solvers with the same name, and the same map from different games (a remake, for instance) can have solvers with the same name.

This is my schema as of now:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Studio 
(
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    position INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    localizedDescription TEXT NOT NULL,
    assetsImageName TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Game 
(
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    position INT NOT NULL,
    localizedDescription TEXT NOT NULL,
    assetsImageName TEXT NOT NULL,
    studio TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name),
    FOREIGN KEY (studio) REFERENCES Studio(name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Map 
(
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    position INT NOT NULL,
    localizedDescription TEXT NOT NULL,
    assetsImageName TEXT NOT NULL,
    game TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, game),
    FOREIGN KEY (game) REFERENCES Game(name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Solver 
(
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    position INT NOT NULL,
    localizedDescription TEXT NOT NULL,
    assetsImageName TEXT NOT NULL,
    map TEXT NOT NULL,
    game TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, map, game),
    FOREIGN KEY (map) REFERENCES Map(name),
    FOREIGN KEY (game) REFERENCES Game(name)
);
```

With the given schema, assume you want to insert a new row on table `Solver`: the DBMS will check whether or not a *map* with primary key `NEW.map` exists, and a game with primary key `NEW.game` exists.

This is useful, but not quite what I need: I would like that before insert on table Solver of a new row, the DBMS checked the existence of exactly one row in `Map` having `name = NEW.map AND game = NEW.game`.

I know I could create a trigger for this, but I would like to know if there exists a syntax that allows me to achieve the same result, so I can leverage `CASCADE DELETE` and `UPDATE` without creating a custom trigger for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the primary key of `Map` is `(name, game)`, you can reference this tuple from the solver in one single foreign key:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Solver (
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    position INT NOT NULL,
    localizedDescription TEXT NOT NULL,
    assetsImageName TEXT NOT NULL,
    map TEXT NOT NULL,
    game TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, map, game),
    FOREIGN KEY (map, game) REFERENCES Map(name, game)
);
```

This ensures that one single row in `Map` is referenced.

Comment: @OliverJacot-Descomes: I ended up adopting this solution, I didn't remember you could adopt this kind of syntax, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In relational databases, foreign key constraints are typically used to enforce referential integrity between tables. However, in your case, you want to ensure a more specific condition before allowing an insert into the Solver table.

Unfortunately, standard SQL does not provide a direct syntax to enforce such a condition at the time of insertion. The typical way to handle this is to use triggers, as you mentioned.

If you want to stick to standard SQL and avoid triggers, one option could be to rethink your schema. For example, you could have a separate table that represents the relationship between maps and games, and then use foreign keys to reference that table from both the Map and Solver tables.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MapGameRelationship (
    map_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    game_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (map_name, game_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (map_name) REFERENCES Map(name),
    FOREIGN KEY (game_name) REFERENCES Game(name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Solver (
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    position INT NOT NULL,
    localizedDescription TEXT NOT NULL,
    assetsImageName TEXT NOT NULL,
    map TEXT NOT NULL,
    game TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, map, game),
    FOREIGN KEY (map, game) REFERENCES MapGameRelationship(map_name, game_name)
);
```

Now, before inserting into the Solver table, you would first need to make sure that there is a corresponding entry in the MapGameRelationship table. This way, you leverage the foreign key constraints for referential integrity.

It's worth noting that while this approach adheres to standard SQL and avoids triggers for the specific check you want, it does introduce an additional table. The choice between triggers and this kind of schema redesign depends on your specific use case and preferences.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My concern with this is that now I'd have to enforce that every Solver is involved in the relationship. I guess I'd have to use a trigger anyway right?

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: I used Google Translate to translate the sentences. I'm sorry if there was any mistake.